# Oracle : SQL - Selecting cust_id with specific App_Nm ( and should not have other app_nm)

Tags: sql, oracle

Please suggest me an approach to select the `CUST_ID` which only has `DEF` AS `APP_NM`. In the below example, the query should only return `123` as the other `cust_id` contains other `App_nm` apart from `DEF`

```
CUST_ID |   APP_NM

XYZ |   ABC

XYZ |   BCD

XYZ |   BB

XYZ |   DEF

XYZ |   DEF

123 |   DEF

123 |   DEF

567 |   BCD

567 |   DEF
```

I tried using count but didn't work out.

Comment: Your sample input shows that duplicate values are possible in the APP_NM column, even for the same CUST_ID. Can APP_NM also be NULL? (Can CUST_ID be NULL?) If either column, or both, can be NULL, how should they be treated? For example: CUST_ID = 990 has two rows, one has APP_NM = ABC and the other has NULL in that column. Do you want to include that CUST_ID in the result? And, if CUST_ID is NULL and has APP_NM = ABC, and that is the only row with CUST_ID is NULL, should it be included in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution to this is to find out `CUST_ID` which don't have `APP_NM = "DEF"` and remove them from all the `CUST_ID` rows. Since you have multiple rows matching this criteria, you can further use `GROUP BY` to return one row. Following is the final query:

```
SELECT CUST_ID 
FROM TestTable1 
WHERE CUST_ID 
NOT IN (SELECT CUST_ID 
        FROM TestTable1 
        WHERE APP_NM != "DEF") 
GROUP BY CUST_ID;
```

> I am calling the table `TestTable1` please replace with appropriate name

I have tested the above query on local `MySQL` installation and following is the table:

```
mysql> select * from TestTable1;
+---------+--------+
| CUST_ID | APP_NM |
+---------+--------+
| XYZ     | ABC    |
| XYZ     | BCD    |
| XYZ     | BB     |
| XYZ     | DEF    |
| XYZ     | DEF    |
| 123     | DEF    |
| 123     | DEF    |
| 567     | BCD    |
| 567     | DEF    |
+---------+--------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Following is the result of the above query:

```
mysql> SELECT CUST_ID FROM TestTable1 WHERE CUST_ID NOT IN (SELECT CUST_ID FROM TestTable1 WHERE APP_NM != "DEF") GROUP BY CUST_ID;
+---------+
| CUST_ID |
+---------+
| 123     |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: But this would list fetch the Cust_ID 567 and XYZ..ryte  ?

Comment: This would fetch all the `CUST_ID` and subtract those who don't have `DEF`. The result wouldn't include `567` if that's what you are asking.